# can't use textbox outside MainWindow method

Tags: c#, wpf, methods

I'm trying to make an integer which consists of numbers that are in box1 (in wpf).
but the compiler won't allow me to compile my code. what's wrong?

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private int addValues()
    {
        int var1 = int.Parse(box1.Text);
    }
}
```

error is:

wpfapplication1.mainwindow.addValues. not all code paths return a value

Comment: What error do you get? Your missing brackets for a start - @Ralt - Its not even valid code so it can't possibly work for you

Comment: int var1 = int.Parse(box1.Text); works for me when I run it

Comment: I added  brackets but it still gives me error:

Comment: What error do you get? Questions seeking debugging help must include a *specific problem*

Comment: says :wpfapplication1.mainwindow.addValues .not all code paths return a value

Comment: You have to decalare you method as void. It's exepcting you to return a value. private void addValues()

Comment: well you can just change `int var1 =` to `return` but then your method doesn't really do much on its own

Comment: Hope it help
[C# for beginners](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/c-fundamentals-development-for-absolute-beginners)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private int addValues()
{
    int var1 = int.Parse(box1.Text);
    return var1;
}
```

Its non-sensible, having a method with a return type but not returns a value.

Make Sensible as,

```
private void addValues()
{
    int var1 = int.Parse(box1.Text);
}
```

Comment: why would i add "return"??

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something in your AddValues (int value) or set it to void.

So for example:

```
private int addValues(){ return int.Parse(box1.Text); }
```

or

```
private void addValues(){ int var1 = int.Parse(box1.Text); }
```

The problem with the last method (your method) does nothing at all (parses a value and does not use it anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have declared the return type of your `addValues` method as an `int` you are telling the compiler you expect this method to *return* a value, therefore at some point your method must return an integer for example

```
private int addValues()
{
    return int.Parse(box1.Text);
}
```

Other options include removing the return type

```
private void addValues()
{
    int var1 = int.Parse(box1.Text);
}
```

Minor Note would be to use `TryParse` to add error handling - This will ensure that if `box1.Text` isn't a valid number, you will still return an integer (0)

```
private int addValues()
{
    int ret_val;
    int.TryParse(box1.Text, out ret_val);
    return ret_val;
}
```