# Trouble calling variables

Tags: c#, wpf, methods

Here's my code (which doesn't compile):

```
        public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private int addValues()
    {
        int var1 = int.Parse(box1.Text);
        int var2 = int.Parse(box2.Text);
        return var1;
        return var2;
    }

    private void plus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int result = addValues(var1, var2);
        int resplus;
        resplus = (var1 + var2);
            res.Text = (resplus.ToString);
    }
}
```

I need to use var1 and var2 in plus_Click method but it says that these two does not exist in the current context.

another thing that i want to add var1 and var2 together and make "resplus" and then show it in textblock (named "res").

Comment: I'd start with a basic C# tutorial, I think it's faster to learn with a good driven path than with random trials!

Comment: Since you are obviously using an answer from your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075123/cant-use-textbox-outside-mainwindow-method) you should probably accept an answer.

Comment: Not sure what you want,i assume you want to add two textbox value ,if so res.Text=int.Parse(box1.Text)+int.Parse(box2.Text);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample you provided have some mistakes. `addValues` method in your code is not accepting any parameters but your code is trying to pass 2 parameters. I have re wrote your code. Please see below code snippet meets your requirement

```
 private int addValues(int var1, int var2)
 {
     return var1 + var2;
 }

 private void plus_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    int result = addValues(int.Parse(box1.Text), int.Parse(box2.Text));
    res.Text = (result.ToString());
 }
```

Comment: res.Text = result.ToString();